# Counting the number of rows that meet certain sum condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, counting

I tried to get the number of rows when the total values of the first x rows in certain column in pandas dataframe exceed certain values. I've read several solutions, but not exactly what I am looking for. Basically I can do this with a loop as shown in the following codes. I just wondering whether there is any commando in python to do this without loop?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series(range(1, 10), index = \
                  range(1, len(range(1,10))+1))})
Count = 0

for i in df.loc[:, 'A']:
    Count += i
    if (Count > 5):
        break

print('Row index:', i)
```

this codes provides me what I want that the number of row when the sum of x first row in column A exceed 5 is three.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum` + `idxmax` should work:

```
df.A.cumsum().gt(5).idxmax()
```

```
3
```

Comment: Thnx. in case the sum of abs value each of entries I can do abs(df.A).cumsum().gt(5).idxmax()